# Visual Studio error during run ASP.net project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to run my app from `visualstudio`(`ASP.net`) but it shows this errors:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   BC32207 The project currently contains references to more than one version of 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage', a direct reference to version 4.1.0.0 and an indirect reference to version 4.3.0.0. Change the direct reference to use version 4.3.0.0 (or higher) of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.   BSS_VX_Service_Infrastructure2  C:\Git\akite-vortex\BSS_VX_Service_Azure\BSS_VX_Infrastructure2\ApplicationUser\ApplicationUserManager.vb   17  Active

Comment: did you check your references?

Comment: I have a lot of references , what should I do?

Comment: I would as a first step try cleaning your project, (generally I just delete the Bin folder in your project as clean does not always work for me), then I would rebuild the project and see if you're getting the error still

Comment: the error is pretty self explanatory, finding the solution may not be, especially when I have no info on your project. My guess is: if it is a solution with multiple projects, one project has `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` with the version explicitly stated and it is referencing a project that has `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` where the version is not stated (it the looks for the most recent version) it is causing this error because the version you are explicitly stating is not the most recent